# how to put a \leq above a \geq which means either of the two situations?

Tags: symbols

I just saw this symbol in an article of 1990 and was curious about how to display it in latex, but haven't found any answers after googling.

Does anybody know that or tell me it is actually rarely used nowadays?

[image]

It's at the end of the paragraph. Thanks a lot!

Comment: that's a < above > not \leq above \geq

Comment: See the inequalities section of the [comprehensive symbol list](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/?lang=en) and you will find the symbol as `\lessgtr` from `amssymb`.

Comment: as with most symbol questions, [detexify would have shown you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuFbV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have two possibilities: `\lessgtr` and `\lesseqgtr`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ amssymb}
\begin{document} %

\[ a\lessgtr b\quad c\lesseqgtr d \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]